# ASP.NET MVC controller always returns "False" on Post/Get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm facing a strange issue, I have created an ASP.NET Web API and added a new controller deriving from `ApiController` and added a new `Test` action. The API is using individual accounts authentication.

But when I send an API call, it always returns "False". I've checked by removing the `[Authorized]` attribute to check if there is something wrong with authorizing the request, but I still get the same error.

He is my controller class:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Healthterest.Controllers
{
    public class PinsController : ApiController
    {  
        public PinsController():base()
        {
        }

        // [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("test")]
        public IHttpActionResult test(string name) 
        {
            return Ok(name);
        }
    }
}
```

`WebApiConfig`:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;

namespace Healthterest
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            //EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            //config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

        private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help to find out what the issue is?

Comment: Why are you putting the parameters in the form-data? Try sending your parameters are raw JSON string in Postman. You should also place break point inside your API method to see if it is even being invoked from Postman.

Comment: @RahulSharma It's not working even with raw JSON string and also breakpoint don't hit even.

Comment: Well if you break point is not being hit, it means that there something wrong in your configuration. Try commenting the `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();` and `config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));` lines and try to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you return string try

```
public string test(string name) 
{
  return Ok(name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, how it will work? it will through runtime error of type System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<string> to string

Comment: Remove OK and return Just return name;

Comment: No luck, i have checked returning the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Healthterest.Controllers
{
    public class PinsController : ApiController
    {  
        public PinsController():base()
        {
        }

        // [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("test")]
        public IHttpActionResult test([FromForm]string name) 
        {
            return Ok(name);
        }
    }
}
```